# Typo3 createquery w/ JOIN returns empty objects

Tags: sql, join, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have 2 Tables, "fe_users" which holds all the information about an user. each user has a consultant. these consultants can upload files for a user he wants. 
the Files are stored in the "t1" table.

so we have:
fe_users (id,name,consultantID,...) and 
t1(id,title,url,userID)

I wanna give the consultant the ability to view all the files he uploaded.

In my repository I have this:

```
$consu = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['consultant'];
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $selectQuery = '
            SELECT t1.user, t1.title, t1.url
            FROM t1
            LEFT JOIN fe_users ON fe_users.uid = t1.user
            WHERE fe_users.consultant ='.$consu;
        $query->statement($selectQuery);

        return $query->execute();
```

This query finds the right amount of objects, but the values for the first object are title = ' ' and user = NULL. The other objects seem to be empty.

In this example the consultant uploaded 4 Files. The fields "title" and "user" are NOT empty! there should be something like this:

```
0=>...
   title =>'Test File No1'
   user => 2015448
   url => 'fileadmin/...'
1 => ...
   title => 'Test No. 2'
   user => 34
```

Debug of query results:

[image]

Comment: Could you please extend your question? I mean because of LEFT JOIN it is possible to get NULL as user, and title could be empty in de DB. It would be nice to know what kind of result U expect and what kind of records are in the two tables (or at least in the t1).

Comment: You should replace the LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN, as LEFT JOINs only benefit here would be to uncover uploads for deleted users. As you don't seem to use the framework functions, I'd suggest your error lies in other parts of the code or your t1 is corrupt with lines where user isn't a TYPO3 uid.